# whether service accounts need additional pricing?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Does google charge for service accounts? Or does service account need additional or specific license?

No related description found in the doc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### No, you can use Google Service Accounts for free

However, mind that if you have a consumer (gmail) account and not a [Google Workspace account](https://workspace.google.com/pricing.html#:%7E:text=Google%20Workspace%20plans%20start%20as,per%20month%20for%20Business%20Plus.) (a domain), you will not be able to use [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

Comment: so service accout could be used normally including impersonation for all the 4 types of Google Workspace account(Business Starter, Business Standard, Business Plus, Enterprise)? How about G Suite for Education?

Comment: You can use a service account for G Suite for education!